# JPA Criteria Query with multiple columns in subquery

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to design a query like such:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE (a AND b AND C) NOT IN
    (SELECT *
     FROM TableB
     WHERE TableB.id != 1234)
```

What I'm really trying to do is get all records from TableA EXCEPT when the columns values of a, b, and c are all in TableB and the ID happens to be 1234.

The catch (or so I think) is that I need to structure this query in a way so that I filter based on this above query, but then it also needs to match a list of other predicates so that it looks something like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<TableA> q = cb.createQuery(TableA.class);
Root<TableA> c = q.from(TableA.class);


Subquery<TableB> sq = q.subquery(TableB.class);
Root<TableB> ac = sq.from(TableB.class);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

sq.select(ac);
sq.where(cb.equal(ac.get("id"), 1234));

predicates.add(cb.not(cb.in(c.get("a")).value(sq)));
predicates.add(cb.not(cb.in(c.get("b")).value(sq)));
predicates.add(cb.not(cb.in(c.get("c")).value(sq)));


.... 
more predicates added
....

q.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
```

The above is my one of my approaches but nothing has gotten the right result.

Answer (score 2):

to solve your problem you can convert the query with IN clause to a query with EXISTS clause. 
Example:

```
SELECT *
   FROM TableA ta
WHERE (ta.a, ta.b) NOT IN
 (SELECT tb.a, tb.c
    FROM TableB tb
    WHERE tb.id != 1234)
```

in

```
SELECT *
  FROM TableA ta
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT 1
       FROM TableB tb
        WHERE ta.a = tb.a AND ta.b = tb.b 
      AND TableB.id != 1234)
```

Your code that use the JPA CriteriaBuilder will be modified as:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<TableA> criteria = cb.createQuery(TableA.class);
Root<TableA> rootTableA = criteria.from(TableA.class);

Subquery<TableB> sq = criteria.subquery(TableB.class);
Root<TableB> rootTableB = sq.from(TableB.class);
sq.select(rootTableB);

List<Predicate> subQueryPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
subQueryPredicates.add(cb.equal(rootTableA.get("a"), rootTableB.get("a")));
subQueryPredicates.add(cb.equal(rootTableA.get("b"), rootTableB.get("b")));
subQueryPredicates.add(cb.equal(rootTableB.get("id"), 1234));
sq.where(subQueryPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));

criteria.where(cb.not(cb.exists(sq)));
```